# sibiling div doesn't take up the space of div with position relative and with negative top

Tags: css, css-position

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">

</div>
<div class="featured">
```

```
</div>

  </div>
```

The css look like this

```
    .header { 
    background: green;

    height:620px;
    }
    .footer {
    background: blue;

    height:200px;
    }
    .featured {
    background: yellow;
    width:500px;
    height:420px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -200px;
    }
```

while pushing a negative top, the silbing div "footer" will not move up accordingly. That's a large empty space in between two divs

This is my code
http://codepen.io/adrianmak/pen/qZRqwy

Comment: you need sticky footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `margin-top:-200px` instead of `top:-200px`. As it is relative element. It will take space even if you are moving it by giving negative top.

```
.featured {
        background: yellow;
        width:500px;
        height:420px;
        margin:-200px auto 0;
        position: relative;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3zuh8q52/)**

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using position relative. When you add top-200px it move that `<div>` up but did not leave his space, you need to use position absolute or negative margin(-ve).

jsfiddle.net/zrsgb2rd/

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want this

```css
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
}
.header { 
        background: green;
        
        height:620px;
        }
        .footer {
        background: blue;
        
        height:200px;
        }
        .featured {
    background: yellow;
    width: 500px;
    height: 420px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="header">

            </div>
            <div class="featured">

            </div>
            <div class="footer">

            </div>
</div>
```